# Safe to use auto_ptr to swap objects without locking in multithreaded environment?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, copy-on-write

I have a few data structures I allocate on the heap that are rarely modified but need fast read access.  One example would be a struct allocated on the heap that is accessed by many threads very frequently in a read-only fashion.  Periodically this struct needs to be re-written and to avoid locking contention I was wondering if it's safe to use `auto_ptr` to basically allow threads that have acquired a reference to keep processing until they're finished but allowing the writer to make a copy of the struct, rewrite it and quickly swap pointers with the new `auto_ptr` instance of the struct.

I got this idea from `CopyOnWriteArrayList` in Java and hoping to perform something similarly performant in C++.

Answer (score 8):

[`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) does not having any thread-safety guarantees when calling a non-const member such as [`reset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr/reset) as you are suggesting. Moreover, neither does [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) which you should consider as a replacement for `auto_ptr` as `auto_ptr` is effectively deprecated.

[`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) *does* provide such thread-saftey guarantees.

What you are typically guaranteed with `shared_ptr` is that the reference count is manipulated in an atomic manner, meaning that you are safe from data races when creating a copy of a `shared_ptr`, provided that nobody is currently modifying the `shared_ptr` at that very moment.

Consider the following use case for your `shared_ptr`. You have a global `shared_ptr<string> sharedString;` that is currently pointing to an instance of `std::string`. It is safe for many threads to call `get()` to retrieve a pointer to the string. They may also create their own shared pointer to it as so: `shared_ptr<string> myString = sharedString;`, provided that nobody is changing what the shared pointer points to.

Now, lets go back and fix the race condition that exists in the example. When it comes time to change what the global shared pointer points to, a thread may be making a copy of it -- that is a problem since it could leave the copy in an inconsistent state. So, we have to make sure that we change and copy it atomically.

Luckily for us, `shared_ptr` provides a number of specializations of the C++11 atomic operations: [`atomic_load`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_load), [`atomic_store`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_store), and [`atomic_exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_exchange).

When making a copy of the `shared_ptr`, use `atomic_load`, and when updating the `shared_ptr`, use `atomic_store`.

Doing it this way is important for two reasons.

1. The atomic_* operations provide a thread-safe way for you to make a copy of the shared pointer.
2. Making a copy means that when the global shared pointer is changed, your copy still points to the old string so your code does not have to worry about having the data it is operated on change when it isn't expecting it.

Now, it is important to note that using thread-safe operations on a `shared_ptr` does not provide any thread safety to the type it points to. You always have to take care that the object pointed to is being used in a thread safe way.

Comment: do you have a link that discusses the thread-safety guarantees for `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Sure! The thread safety is explained explained in the C++ standard under the heading `[util.smartptr.shared.atomic]`. And here is a link to the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2632.html) that added the functionality it explains the usage and provides some code.

Comment: Any ideas on a similar mechanism on gcc wo/ c++11 extensions?  Can I use gcc intrinsics instead of c++11's atomic_* features?

Comment: Actually, on second thought, if I guarantee pointer alignment to 8 bytes on my x86_64 arch, reads and writes would be atomic so swapping out the pointer to the shared_ptr should be able to be achieved without any kind of explicit locking, no?

Comment: @stgtscc You could use an atomic pointer type but there would still be a data race on object destruction. Depending on how it is used you would be at risk of a [use-after-free](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/416.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can reassign an auto_ptr on the fly with reset(), by the way, it destroys the object instance formerly pointed.

However, auto_ptr is deprecated by unique_ptr, which have a swap() function which somewhat seems to stick to what you are seeking.

Keep in mind that these classes are *not* thread-safe.